# Physical Plan and Optimizing a Non-Equi Join in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark SQL 2.4.0. I have a couple of tables as below:

CUST table:

```
id | name | age | join_dt
-------------------------
12 | John | 25 | 2019-01-05
34 | Pete | 29 | 2019-06-25
56 | Mike | 35 | 2020-01-31
78 | Alan | 30 | 2020-02-25
```

REF table:

```
eff_dt
------
2020-01-31
```

The requirement is to select all the records from `CUST` whose `join_dt` is `<=` `eff_dt` in the `REF` table. So, for this simple requirement, I put together the following query:

version#1:

```
select 
c.id, 
c.name, 
c.age, 
c.join_dt
from cust c
inner join ref r
on c.join_dt <= r.eff_dt;
```

Now, this creates a `BroadcastNestedLoopJoin` in the physical plan and hence the query takes a long time to process this.

**Question 1**:

Is there a better way to implement this same logic without a `BNLJ` being induced and execute the query faster? Is it possible to alleviate the `BNLJ` ?

**Part 2**:

Now,I broke the query into 2 parts as:-

version#2:

```
select c.id, c.name, c.age, c.join_dt
from cust c
inner join ref r
on c.join_dt = r.eff_dt --equi join
union all
select c.id, c.name, c.age, c.join_dt
from cust c
inner join ref r
on c.join_dt < r.eff_dt; --theta join
```

Now, for the Query in `Version#1`, the physical plan shows that the `CUST` table is scanned only **once**, whereas the physical plan for the Query in `Version#2` indicates that the same input table `CUST` is scanned **twice** (Once for each of the 2 queries combined with a `union`). However, I am surprised to find that `Version#2` executes faster than `version#1`.

**Question 2**:

How does `version#2` execute faster than `version#1` although `version#2` scans the table **twice** as opposed to **once** in case of `version#1`, and also the fact that both the versions induce a `BNLJ` ?

Can anyone please clarify. Please let me know if additional information is required.
Thanks.

Comment: How many records are there in `ref` table?

Comment: there will be only 1 record

Comment: It is possible for you to collect `ref` table row to a variable? Then using `filter` you could avoid join altogether.

Comment: @Izhar Ahmed thanks for your reply. Since we use Spark SQL API queries, I don't have the option to put that date in a variable. Btw, will it be possible for you to shed any light on my Question#2 please ?